# anime/manga/cel-shaded style characters

Tags: shader, unity-game-engine, blender

Making a game using Blender for 3D models and Unity for the game engine. Just wondering if anyone knows any links to pages that give a tutorial on Japanese anime style 3D modeling, texturing and shading through Blender.

I'm actually looking to create a cel-shaded look eventually (read: Okami/Jet Set Radio style) and I'm kind of stuck with the design stuff. I'm not a Blender expert by any means, and still kind of new to the design side of things (I'm a programmer by trade), so please don't vote me down too hard. I've tried googling, but there doesn't seem to be much in the way of what I'm after.

The only thing I've found really is a plugin for Blender called freestyle, or using the ToonShader shading tool. If there are any good tutorials or anything, I'm really happy to sit through them. The art style is called sumi-e, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender has nothing to do with how the model is rendered in the end, aside from texture mapping. In order to develop the look your looking for, check out unity shader lab(a language that comes with the program). It allows you to write platform independent vertex and pixel shaders, which you can use to create the effect your looking for.

In terms of your model, its simply an issue of artistic prefference. You model your characters like any other humanoid, and exaggerate certain elements to get the anime look. The shaders will also add a whole lot to the effect.

For textures, try to stick to fairly undetailed painterly textures for environments, combined with a few patterns for any characters or props.

Comment: Sounds good. Any idea how I'd also go about exaggerated outlines on assets too (thinking of Okami style specifically here)? Are there any tutorials you know of that would be really helpful for this?